# How to tell if current revision is tagged

Tags: git

I would like to know how to tell if the current revision is tagged and extract the tag name.

Something a bit simpler than listing all different tags and comparing the hashes with a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last tag in the branch with `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` and check if it points to the HEAD commit.

You can see the latest commit "decorated" with branches and tags: `git log --decorate -1`.

Comment: Isn't `short` (which doesn't include tags in decorations) the default decorate mode? I thought you'd need `--decorate=full` to add them in log output. (However : let's note this might have changed along git versions history.)

Comment: The difference between `short` and `full` is not about including tags in decorations — they're always included. In `short` mode `git` shows just names (like `master`), in `full` mode `git` shows full names (`refs/heads/master`).

Answer (score 4):

`git describe --exact-match` will only return a tag if the current commit is tagged. You can run that and check the error code.

```
$ git describe --exact-match
fatal: no tag exactly matches '609ed4a5b012590d1017c502823dc0fc4c80de50'
$ echo $?
128
$ git checkout v2018-11-07-101858
Note: checking out 'v2018-11-07-101858'.
...
HEAD is now at 746f26a3 ...
$ git describe --exact-match
v2018-11-07-101858
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: @SteveMoretz could you elaborate? In what way did it not work? Has the describe command changed? Does the return code not work on a particular platform?

Comment: I was really tired that night I don't remember the exact situation, I think it was giving me an older tag than the latest commit which wasn't tagged, I didn't downvote your answer however just a heads up, maybe something like that happens to you too, I ended up using : `git tag --points-at HEAD` that night.